# Connect 2 computers without wifi/router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi without having a screen nor direct access to the router, Is there a way to connect these 2 computers? (without buying switch or router). Afterwards, by accessing through `ssh`, Wi-fi could be enabled.

I've read an ad-hoc network could be set, or using an ethernet cable. Buy I'm not sure how feasible this approaches are. Any hints here are welcome.

**Edit:** OS is Raspbian, and the laptop is running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think with these two components you could achieve that:

1. Connect Raspberry Pi to your computer using a **crossover ethernet cable**. This cable will make sure that the sending/receiving works properly even on similar devices (ie when you don't have a switch<->computer scenario). EDIT: As various people pointed out in the comments, this is only needed when your computer doesn't implement Auto-MDIX (ie when your PC doesn't have gigabit ethernet).
2. Configure a basic **DHCP server** (for example using isc-dhcp-server on Linux or tftpd32 on Windows) on the computer to configure the Raspberry Pi
3. Either check the leases on the DHCP server or scan the network to find the address of the Pi
4. Connect to the Pi using SSH

Also note that SSH is disabled in many distributions for the Raspberry PI. Make sure that you either use a distribution that has SSH enabled by default or mount the SD-card on your computer to edit the SSH configuration.

Comment: You may not need a crossover cable with a 'modern' computer on the other end.

Comment: Novadays network adapter using Auto MDI-X so any Cat5 and better cable is suitable

Comment: To be more precise: Auto-MDX is standard for Gigabit (and faster) network interfaces. it is NOT default for 100 Mb/s and slower network adapters. RaspBerry PI version 4 has Gigabit but earlier models only have 100 Mb/s. Either way a straight or cross-over UTP may or may not work as Auto-MDX is not guaranteed to work if one of the sides doesn't support it. You may have to set the PC side to non-MDX and use a cross-cable anyway in order to get connection.

Comment: tftpd32 is a small DHCP/TFTP program for Windows. Very useful for things like this. (And is portable. Doesn't need installation. Still requires admin-rights to run though.)

Comment: @Tonny Thanks! I added all these infos to my original answer.

Comment: @Tonny: It is not part of the spec for 100 Mbps Ethernet, that's true, but _in practice_  it seems that even 100 Mbps hardware has been universally including this feature for well over a decade.

Comment: @Tonny I rechecked the hardware documentation and Raspberry PI forums and it appears that all Raspberry Pis with an RJ45 connector [support Auto-MDIX](https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Components), as as user1686 claims, this appears to have been implemented on all Raspberry Pis since model B although not required by standard.

Comment: @jvda I didn't now it was enabled by default on the older PI models. (Never needed to use it.) That is good to know. As for most 100 Mb/s NICs in the last decade having it on by default... My experience is very different. On SOHO equipment about 50/50. On business and industrial computers it is quite rare.

Comment: @Tonny Every computer I have owned since the late-1990's has had auto-sensing ethernet ports.

Comment: @GlenYates How many computers in total is that? I'm a sysadmin in a large organization for 26 years now (and been in IT longer than that). I deal with approx 500 new computers each year. Not to mention the 30 or so family and friends for which I also install/update their personal and/or business computers (a bunch of them have small businesses without an IT department).

Comment: @Tonny [LAN9514](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/LAN9514) as used in the Pi3 does support Auto-MDIX. Same goes for [LAN9512.](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/LAN9512) used in some other Pis. Sure, it can be disabled, but considered Raspberry's target audience it'd be shooting themselves in the foot. In case you know the difference (I don't), it's the HP variant, not the IEEE one.

Comment: Windows has had a DHCP server built in since ages. Just set a static IP. You may have to enable internet sharing too, I can't remember for sure. Done, the other end will get an IP over DHCP.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer cause it does not require a wifi network around. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the Raspberry PI OS you’re going to use, you can just slap a `wpa_supplicant.conf` on the boot partition and the OS will detect and use it to connect to a wireless network.

Raspbian for example supports this.

The file could look like this:

```
country=us
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="my-wifi-net"
    psk="the network password"
}
```

The `scan_ssid=1` is optional and only required when you have a hidden network. You may want to replace the country code as appropriate, for example to use channels > 11.

You have to make sure to use UNIX line breaks. You can find more information [in the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md).

To find the Pi’s IP address, you can take a look at your router’s web interface or scan the network, using Angry IP Scanner or the like.

---

If you cannot use this method for whatever reason, refer to the other answer.

Comment: This would be an excellent option to connect to an _existing_ network, right? Correct me if I'm wrong but what I understood from the initial question is that there is no network in place. Is there also an approach to use the preconfigured sogftware on a raspberry pi to actually create an SSID?

Comment: I wrote I don't have a screen. Hence, do you mean to plug the SD card to a laptop to modify the OS `/boot` ? that sounds cool!

Comment: also, idk why ```country=us
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1``` is needed, but i'd include the rest yeah

Comment: It's just what the official docs say, no idea. Yes, you'd use a SD card reader to access the data from your PC.

Comment: Country is required for regulatory reasons, Raspiban refuses to activate WiFi (and possible Bluetooth) if it's not set. (Obviously if you're not USA set this to your county code). The other bit allows members of the group netdev to use wpa front ends (eg wpa_cli)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/#:%7E:text=install%20raspberry%20pi%20os%20using%20raspberry%20pi%20imager) to flash your sd card, for version 1.6 or greater, the [Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/#:%7E:text=install%20raspberry%20pi%20os%20using%20raspberry%20pi%20imager) comes with [advanced options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/). Press `Ctrl-Shift-X` for more options, including configuring wifi.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this require to re flash every time the network changes?